# rust uwrap_or_else return a reference

Tags: rust

I have a situation in a piece of dynamic programming where i either want to get the pre computed results, or call a function to compute these results.

This is the situation in short

```
let previous_results HashMap<String, Result> = HashMap::new();

for i in some_values {
   let result = previous_results.get(i).unwrap_or_else(|| calculate_results(i))
}
```

The rust compiler justly complains about the function call and it says

```
expected reference `&HashMap<std::string::String, Result>`
      found struct `HashMap<std::string::String, Result>`
```

This is because `.get` normally returns a reference to the object,and not the actual object, but the function returns an actual object. So i could just return a reference to what the function returns

```
let result = previous_results.get(i).unwrap_or_else(|| &calculate_results(i))
```

Note the `&`in front of the function call. But this is also an issue, cause a reference to something that is scoped within the anonymous function will be meaningless as soon as the anonymous function returns. And rust complains

```
cannot return reference to temporary value
returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

What am i missing here? What is the correct approach to do this in rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot return a reference to a local value (in your case the `unwrap_or_else` callback), because as that local value is dropped the reference is invalidated.

You could clone the value taken from the map, but that is usually not the most efficient way to go. And maybe the value isn't even cloneable.

So, that is one of the use cases for [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

for i in some_values {
   let result = previous_results
       .get(i)
       .map(Cow::Borrowed)
       .unwrap_or_else(|| Cow::Owned(calculate_results(i)));
}
```

And they you use the `result` more or less normally, as it implements `Deref<Result>`. But remember that the value inside may be borrowed from the map, so the `Cow<'_, Result>` value keeps the map borrowed.

Funnily, while the name `Cow` stands for *Clone-On-Write*, many times it is used when you need an *Owned_Or_Borrowed*.

The main drawback of `Cow` is that it requires the value to be `ToOwned`, that basically means to implement `Clone`, because of that `C` in the name. If your `Result` type is not `Clone`, I think that currently there is no solution in `std` but it is easy to implement your own, or use an available crate such as [`maybe-owned`](https://crates.io/crates/maybe-owned).

Answer (score 2):

@rodrigo already answered my question with the correct approach, but I was a bit confused of what magic `Cow` was doing that solved my issue, so i want to clarify for others that might be confused as well.

The crux of the issue for my problem was that `.get` returns a reference to an element in the HashMap, but the function called by `unwrap_or_else` needs to return an owned value or it wont be valid once we are outside of the anonymous function scope.

So the solution that is a bit hidden in @rodrigo's answer is the `map` called after `get`, which can be used to turn whatever is returned by `get` into an owned value, so that `unwrap_or_else` can return an owned value, and the problem is solved.

`Cow` helps because cloning the value returned by `.get` is not the most efficient thing to do, unless you do need a copy later on. So Cow abstracts away the ownership and gets `.get` and `unwrap_or_else` to return the same type, without having to clone anything.

@rodrigo's answer should still be the accepted answer as it correctly solves the problem, but i wanted to provide a bit more context as i wasn't quite sure how the ownership was resolved.